# Преобразование числа в строку методом toString

Tags: javascript

Почему объект числа не преобразовывается в строку? Ведь я в прототипе определил метод `toString`:

```js
Number.prototype.toString = function() {
  return "wrwer";
}
var a = 5;
console.log(a + '');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Метод вы переопределили, и вызов его вручную выдаёт нужный результат:

```js
Number.prototype.toString = function() {
  return "wrwer";
}
var a = 5;
console.log(a.toString());
```

Однако при использовании оператора сложения метод `toString` **не вызывается**.
Как этот оператор работает можно посмотреть [в спецификации ECMAScript](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus).
В частности, так как один из операндов (`''`) является строкой, то второй (`a`) тоже приводится к строке. Но делается это с помощью [абстрактной операции ToString](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tostring), которая, [применительно к числам](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type), формирует строку по описанному в спецификации алгоритму, не вызывая метод `toString`.

---

[Стандартная реализация](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-number.prototype.tostring) метода `Number.prototype.toString` использует внутри себя `ToString`, если в качестве основания системы счисления в `toString` передано `10` (или ничего не передано - `10` является значением по умолчанию). В противном случае (при основании от `2` до `9` и от `11` до `36`) алгоритм зависит от реализации в конкретном браузере, но вряд ли сильно отличается от стандартного.

Comment: А есть русскоязычная статья на эту тему?

Comment: @АртёмPeGaS самой спецификации на русском я не нашел, да и вряд ли кто-то переводил столь объёмный текст. Разница между `toString` и `ToString` - это очень тонкий и редкий момент, поэтому найти информацию об этом (кроме как в спецификации) тоже, скорее всего, будет крайне проблемно.

Comment: А вы могли бы вкратце объяснить разницу, или стоит ли вообще заострять на этом внимание? (возможно на практике это вообще не пригодится)

Comment: @АртёмPeGaS на практике это вряд ли когда-либо пригодится. Не припомню чтобы когда-то видел переопределённый `toString` у `Number` Но я в ответ добавил описание стандартного `Number.prototype.toString`.